# URL object in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to parse a URL (usually https, but not necessarily) into it's component pieces and store them in separate fields in a table.  I tried to use the URL object as documented in this writeup:

[https://javascript.info/url][1]

Here's my user defined function:

```
use database ...;
use schema ...;

create or replace procedure sc_test()
    RETURNS varchar
    LANGUAGE javascript
    execute as owner 
    as 
    $$


    var url = new URL('http://myurl.com');
    result = url.protocol;

    return result;
    $$
    ;


call sc_test()
```

The output of the script is:
JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: URL is not defined in SC_HUB_TEST at ' var url = new URL('http://myurl.com');' position 14 stackstrace: SC_TEST line: 4

So I had thought this URL was some sort of built in component available to all Javascript programs, but on Snowflake, it apparently is missing.  How can I use this or maybe something else?  My goal is to reliably parse a URL into is component pieces (ie. protocol,  hostname, port, path/query string arguments, etc).

Bonus points if someone points me to a Snowflake documentation page that shows all the Javascript functions and objects that I can use.  I already have been to this https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference.html, and I saw things like how to create a UDF, and other SQL functions, but not internal Javascript library references.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference.html
[1]: https://javascript.info/url

Comment: Snowflake's JavaScript does not include some libraries that browsers typically have, so you have to be careful about library references in any code samples. URL appears to be in a library that's not core. Snowflake includes the "snowflake" library in stored procedures but not UDFs. It also includes a date library called "sfdate". You can see what's in the core ECMAScript specification (official name because of trademark issues) here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/.  As demircioglu mentions, you can use the PARSE_URL function, so you don't have to write one in JS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [PARSE_URL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/parse_url.html)

You can parse all elements in URL just like json